# How should I have worded my question so it wasn't VTCed?

Tags: support

I recently asked a question ([What would be the worldwide response if Russia launches a nuke into Ukraine?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/71183/what-would-be-the-worldwide-response-if-russia-launches-a-nuke-into-ukraine)) that I consider to be not dissimilar in terms of questioning style to, for example, this question: [What would setting up a no-fly zone by NATO over Ukraine actually mean?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/71443/what-would-setting-up-a-no-fly-zone-by-nato-over-ukraine-actually-mean). But my question was voted to close due to being "opinion-based".

Both seem to have no clear evidence that can be used to support answers; they'd both have opinions as their answers. Both ask a hypothetical question.

I've asked for feedback on the question to refine my questioning technique for the future but I haven't received any answers.

What refinements to my linked question above should I make to produce more acceptable questions in the future?

Comment: FYI, I've already read this: https://politics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask

Comment: I don't see how we can answer the question as outside of WW2 nuclear weapons have never been used against an opponent in a war and it is unclear how the world would react.

Comment: @JoeW But the actual question in the description does provide a guideline for answering the question, in terms of any agreements or policies or the like.

Comment: If a nuclear attack actually does happen I don't think that NATO/EU/UN would really matter at that point. What would be more important is if any other nuclear country concludes that the attack is a threat to them that requires a response and it is hard to say how they will treat it. At that point the pretty much all of our norms are gone.

Answer (score 3):

Your "guidance" in how to answer the question should have been the question itself.  Rather than asking "what would happen," if your question instead asked "are there any actions required by the currently-existing treaties in response to..," then it would leave no room for speculation.

Comment: That's useful, thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Your question wasn't "what would it take to launch a nuke into Ukraine", which could have gotten factual answers (as well as probably downvotes for being pushy if you had asked it).  It was "what would the reaction be on this hypothetical event", which is off topic.

If the other question had been "What would Russia's reaction to NATO planes shooting down Russian ones in a no-fly zone?" that would **also** be off limit.

"What would Russia's reaction be to a no-fly zone?" would be somewhat answerable:  Putin has *already* signified it would be considered an act of war.  Even without that pronouncement and anyone can remark that such a zone would involve shooting at Russian planes which would likely be horribly escalatory.

It's a fine line and sometimes it snowballs by the first vote to close and downvotes being followed by others.  So there is no obvious good and bad though the "Russia launches nuke at Ukraine" **is** likely over the top to many people.